# What protocal XDocument.Load user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, linq-to-xml

I am loading XML from a url using `XDocument.Load`. It seems to work locally but fails in server. I have IIS 7, ASP.NET MVC 2 application. What specific protocol the above function uses? What IIS settings I need to check? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give exception details ?

Answer (score 0):

please post your code:

```
Dim doc As XDocument 
doc = XDocument.Load("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8842115/sample.xml") 

For Each node In doc.Descendants("first") 

  Console.WriteLine(CType(node.Element("no"), String)) 

Next
```

Comment: I would like to know what is going on underneath that request?